# how to count number of lines in each several paragraph

Tags: python

I wish to count the number of lines in paragraph from text file which looks like this:

text file =

```
black
yellow
pink

hills
mountain
liver

barbecue
spaghetti
```

I want to know that the last paragraph has less or more lines than others and  then remove it.

The result I want:

```
black
yellow
pink

hills
mountain
liver
```

I tried in this way:

```
c = []
with open(file) as paragraph:

    index = 0
    for line in paragraph:

        if line.strip():
            index += 1
    c.append(index)
```

but, I was struck that this could be too complicated...maybe?

Answer (score 2):

The file **test_line.txt**

```
black
yellow
pink

hills
mountain
liver

barbecue
spaghetti
```

1. Start counting the line using `index`.
2. On line 6 check if a new Line came, and append the list with the counted lines of paragraphs and reset the `index` to `0`
3. On line 9 counting the lines
4. On line 11 append for the last paragraph

***Now you have got a list which contains number of lines in each paragraph. Do anything with the list as you please.***

Here's your modified code-

```
file = "test_line.txt"
c = []
with open(file) as paragraph:

    index = 0
    for line in paragraph:
        if line == '\n':
            c.append(index)
            index = 0
        else:
            index+=1
    c.append(index)

print(c)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[3, 3, 2]
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could split by `\n\n` and use a list comprehension:

> test.txt

```
black
yellow
pink

hills
mountain
liver

barbecue
spaghetti
```

> test.py

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
  output = f.read()
  x = [len(i.split('\n')) for i in output.split('\n\n')]
  print(x)
```

Output:

```
[3, 3, 2] # 2 is the one you want to remove
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

lines = open("test.txt").read().splitlines()
paragraphs = [list(groups) for keys, groups in groupby(lines, lambda x: x != "") if keys]
```

Where you read the file and split on new lines. This will give you:

```
[['black', 'yellow', 'pink'], [''], ['hills', 'mountain', 'liver'], [''], ['barbecue', 'spaghetti']]
```

From there you can use `itertools.groupby` to group them to a list of sublists and do some operations to determine what you want.

Output:

```
[['black', 'yellow', 'pink'], ['hills', 'mountain', 'liver'], ['barbecue', 'spaghetti']]
```

So now each sublist is a paragraph that you can count on it. So for the first paragraph, something like this: `len(sublists[0])` will give you 3. For example:

```
for paragraph in paragraphs:
  print(len(paragraph))
```

Output:

```
3
3
2
```

Now you just need to put your logic to finish this. You can use `del sublists[i]` to delete the `i`th sublist.